# jQuery call function randomly in multiples

Tags: jquery

I'm coding a game that has a 2 minute timer countdown - within that time i want an alert to popup randomly in multiples of 10 seconds. The alert could be called at 10 seconds, 30 seconds or even 110 seconds - as long as they are in multiples of 10.

```
(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (60000 - 10000)) + 10000;
    setTimeout(function() {
            alert("hi");
            loop();  
    }, rand);
}());
```

I've found some code whilst doing some research but I don't think I've quite got it right?

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Al

Comment: Please describe the error / behaviour you are seeing when you run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:-

`Math.round((Math.random() * 10) + 1);` giving you a number 1 and 11

`* 10000` to get seconds from 10 to 110, in intervals of 10.

`clearTimeout` incase the 2nd/3rd/etc timer goes over 2 minutes

```js
var randTimer;

setTimeout(function() {
  alert('Game Over');
  clearTimeout(randTimer);
}, 120000); // 2 minutes

(function randomTimer() {
  var rand = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) + 1); // 1 to 11
  randTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Random');
    randomTimer();
  }, rand * 10000); // 10 to 110 seconds
}());
```

Comment: Works great - I changed 'rand * 10000' to 5000 so that it gets called at least a few times during the 2 minutes. 

Many thanks